# What does 騷債 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, cantonese

I understand [債](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%82%B5) means debt, because context fits. Louisa Mak won TVB's 2015 Miss Hong Kong first place. TVB has credited Louisa money, publicity, fame. So it's reasonable for reporter to ask if she repays a debt to TVB by attending Miss H.K. 2020.

But what means [騷 on CUHK's Chinese Character Database](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%A8%B7)? I screen-shot [0:16](https://youtu.be/me7W7BmFzjI?t=16). They are speaking Cantonese.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reporter actually said "還 show" (fulfill an obligation for attending a show)

騷 /sou1/ in the subtitle is a Cantonese sound-alike word for the English word "Show"

"騷債" = 'show debt' (the obligations for attending shows)

*I don't call it a loan word because it is not officially listed in the dictionary, unlike 巴士(bus), 的士 (taxi) and 士多 (store)*