# The use of ''call'' in Chinese. e.g. '' 为你打call ''

Tags: grammar

I came across the phrase ''为你打call'' recently in a Douyin video.

I recalled seeing ''call'' a few times without really paying much attention to it.

It seems it has made it's way into the Chinese lexicon, kind of like ''fighting'' or ''hold不住''.

I asked a Chinese friend what ''为你打call'' means and they said it means that you support someone.

Can anyone explain more clearly the meaning of ''call'' as Chinese people are using it ?

What are some other examples of the use of ''call'' in Chinese ?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the video?

Comment: @r13 Sorry I can't find that video again. If I come across any more ''call'' appearances I'll add them to my question as examples.

Comment: It could be a program/show in which "call" means "good/excellent"- "給你加個好"?!

Answer (score 1):

'Call' here seems to be a direct insertion of an English word into a Chinese sentence. It is very common in Hong Kong Cantonese.

This post: [What does 騷債 mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/41139/what-does-%e9%a8%b7%e5%82%b5-mean/41140#41140) is a good example

> they said it means that you support someone.

If it is the case, then 'Call' here is short for 'phone call' and 打call means 'making a phone call'

Making a phone call to relevant departments is a method of supporting someone, for example, call or text to vote for someone in a singing contest

Answer (score 1):

打call comes from コール in the context of Japanese live performance culture. It refers to swaying glow sticks, clapping or calling out etc during live events to show support to the performers. Usually it's only used to mean a fan's support for a celebrity (and only widely used in those subcultures).

Comment: I agree. I learned the same explanation somewhere else. Making phone calls doesn’t make any sense.